# WowWee MiP command over Bluetooth in Linux Shell with gatttool

Tags: android, linux, shell, bluetooth

I try to command my MiP robot using Linux shell command (Ubuntu 14.04).

Before trying this, i have used the official Android App and i have sniffed all bluetooth packet with the "Snoop HCI Bluetooth log" integrated in Android developer options.

When i gave the order to turn left (for example) to my robot using this app, it appears that the app send :

```
Opcode: Write Command (0x52)
Handle: 0x0013
Value: 7800XX (replacing XX by some different value according the direction)
```

This is visible in Wireshark (i can't post image...).

I try to reproduce this using gatttool in a shell.

With this tool, the syntaxe is :

```
char-write-cmd <cmd> <handle> value
```

I have done some try with different values like this:

```
[CON][EE:AA:BB:A2:FE:FF][LE]> char-write-cmd 0x52 0x0013 0x78 0x00 0x60
[CON][EE:AA:BB:A2:FE:FF][LE]> char-write-cmd 0x52 0x0013 0x780060
[CON][EE:AA:BB:A2:FE:FF][LE]> char-write-cmd 0x52 0x0013 78 00 60
[CON][EE:AA:BB:A2:FE:FF][LE]> char-write-cmd 0x52 0x0013 0x60 0x00 0x78
[CON][EE:AA:BB:A2:FE:FF][LE]> char-write-cmd 0x52 0x0013 0x600078
[CON][EE:AA:BB:A2:FE:FF][LE]> char-write-cmd 0x52 0x0013 60 00 78
```

But without success...

My question is:

How can i send multiple byte for the value parameter ?

Best Regards

PiF

PS: Sorry for my bad English :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. Maybe this can help someone.

The right syntax command is:

```
[CON][EE:AA:BB:A2:FE:FF][LE]> char-write-cmd 0x0013 780060
```

The command

```
char-write-cmd
```

Put always the 0x52 (gatt or  bluetooth) opcode command

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the official Bluetooth specification located at https://github.com/WowWeeLabs/MiP-BLE-Protocol this should provide good documentation about hte commands.